# How to tell when DBO was changed (and if possible, by whom)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am looking for a way to track when the DBO account is changed.  For example, if someone uses `sp_changedbowner` is there a way, after the fact, to determine when this occurred, and even better, what user was used to make the change?

This would be useful in tracking changes in the event of a database breach where teh attacker changed permissions, for example, so I suspect the possibility must be there.

I've been attempting to google it and look for it in the MSDN documentation, but I'm just not finding this.

Comment: I'm guessing there may be some sort of auditing that needs to be turned on/configured first.  Sorry if this is a newbie question.  I usually only deal with SQL Server from a Developer's perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in the default trace. Whether you use `sp_changedbowner` or the proper, modern syntax, it will show up as the latter:

```
alter authorization on database::[foo] to [bar]
```

You can retrieve the information this way:

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

SELECT 
   @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
   CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
FROM    sys.traces
WHERE   is_default = 1;

SELECT * -- whittle down to the meaningful trace columns
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
WHERE EventClass = 152
ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
```

Now, the event might have happened a long time ago, so it won't necessarily still be in the trace.

Comment: Thank you!  I['s not returning any results, when running against the master database, or another database on the server.  I changed the principal that owns the DBO role and re-ran the query, and still no results.  Is it possible my trace just isnt' turned on, or something is configured properly?

Comment: @DavidStratton I'll confess I was only able to test on SQL Server 2012 due to VM availability. It's possible that this specific event is not included in the default trace prior to SQL Server 2012 (you can check this in the trace-related catalog views); it's also possible that you shut the trace off.

Comment: Thank you! I eliminated the WHERE clause and got results, so I think the trace is turned on.  I'll look deeper on MSDN and see if I can find more info.  This pointed me in the right direction, at least.